# Como implementar WebSockets en retrofit?

Tags: android, apache, retrofit, websocket

Estoy intentando otro método de comunicación `Cliente-Servidor`, he investigado al respecto y existe `WebSocket` que seria un canal de comunicación bidireccional (entre `cliente-servidor`), estuve usando `retrofit`, quisiera saber si al usar `WebSocket` debo dejar de emplear métodos de `retrofit`, o ambos trabajan de la mano? o sencillamente se debe trabajar `WebSocket` con `Apache`? alguna ayuda de como se implementan estos métodos?

Comment: Los websockets están pensados para la web, por lo tanto no tienen una buena implementación en el aréa nativa. por lo tanto es mejor usar sockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta a mi pregunta, `Retrofit` no soporta `websockets`, por ende no puedo mezclar ambos métodos, sencillamente pueden usarse ambas formas para ejecutar métodos distintos según las necesidades o requerimientos de la `app`.